# vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer results in solid color image

Tags: c++, vulkan

I tried to alternate [Sascha Willems Render Headless example](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/bb3b336e53d239b706ca012751242e75e8f487d4/examples/renderheadless/renderheadless.cpp#L681-L774) of the Vulkan API to use a buffer instead of an image on the host side. I changed the code for copying back the image (lines 687 - 775) to the following:

```
//create buffer
VkBuffer buffer;
VkDeviceMemory memory;
createBuffer(
    VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT,
    VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT,
    &buffer,
    &memory,
    width * height * 4,
    nullptr
);

//create cmd buf
VkCommandBufferAllocateInfo cmdBufAllocateInfo = vks::initializers::commandBufferAllocateInfo(commandPool, VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY, 1);
VkCommandBuffer copyCmd;
VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkAllocateCommandBuffers(device, &cmdBufAllocateInfo, &copyCmd));
VkCommandBufferBeginInfo cmdBufInfo = vks::initializers::commandBufferBeginInfo();
VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkBeginCommandBuffer(copyCmd, &cmdBufInfo));

//build copy cmd
VkBufferImageCopy bufImgCpy{};
bufImgCpy.imageSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
bufImgCpy.imageSubresource.layerCount = 1;
bufImgCpy.imageExtent.width = width;
bufImgCpy.imageExtent.height = height;
bufImgCpy.imageExtent.depth = 1;

vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer(copyCmd,
    colorAttachment.image, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL,
    buffer, 1, &bufImgCpy);

VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkEndCommandBuffer(copyCmd));

submitWork(copyCmd, queue);

//map buffer
vkMapMemory(device, memory, 0, VK_WHOLE_SIZE, 0, (void**)&imagedata);
```

However, whilst the original code works, mine just gives me an image with only the background color/clear value. I already consulted the specification but couldn't find a hint on what I'm doing wrong.

I'm running on an AMD RTX 480 (Driver: Radeon 19.12.12), Windows 10 1909 with the LunarG SDK in Version 1.1.114.0.

Comment: FYI this approach appears to work fine on my nVidia RTX 2080.

Comment: Think, I'll set up my Laptop (nVidia 940MX & Intel HD 620) and give it a try. Maybe it's an AMD thing?

Comment: Note, it working on my nVidia device doesn't actually mean the code is bug free.  Different devices tend to each have situations where the driver internals means an operation works whether you have barriers or not, and the barrier translates into a noop on that device.  Doesn't mean the code is consistent with the spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original looks incorrect to me. It should perform a *memory domain operation* via `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT`.

Your code should also include a `vkCmdPipelineBarrier` with `dstStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT`.

Comment: I don't get why you'd need any barriers at all here.  The rendering is executed via a command buffer sent to `submitWork`, which appears to wait on the cmd buffer being fully executed before it returns.  So there is a `submitWork` that executes the render, then another `submitWork` that executes the copy to a buffer, then a mapping of coherent host-visible memory.  It's inefficient, but shouldn't need any barriers.

Comment: Tried your approach but had no success. Shouldn't the fence in submitWork() ensure completion anyway? I also tried putting the original code before mine and let it create two different files. The original is correct whilst mine has the same problem again.

Comment: @BassGuru Fence makes a _memory dependency_ but not _memory domain op_. Do note that if Fence did `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT` would have no reason to exist in the first place. @Jherico `HOST_COHERENT` covers host domain, but not device domain. Unless you also use `DEVICE_COHERENT_BIT_AMD`.

Comment: @BassGuru Can I see the `vkCmdPipelineBarrier` you tried, just to be sure?

Comment: `vkCmdPipelineBarrier(copyCmd, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr)`. Tried it before and after the actual copy command. Tried also `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT` for `srcStageMask`

Comment: @BassGuru That's not correct. Should be `srcStage=TRANSFER` and should have `VkMemoryBarrier` or `VkBufferMemoryBarrier` with `TRANSFER_WRITE` -> `HOST_READ` access masks. After the copy.

Comment: Tried both struct as you suggested. Unfortunatelly, again I had no success. Tried every combination, even passed them simultanious.

Comment: The thing that puzzles me is, that when I map the buffer before the copy command and inspect the memory I can clearly see that there has been copying done. But somehow only the clear value gets transfered like there hasn't been any rendering.

Comment: Hm are you actually writing it out correctly? How have you modified that code? I only had to change to `imagedata += 4*width`.

Comment: good call @krOoze ... if the code still have `imagedata += subResourceLayout.rowPitch` in it, but `subResourceLayout` is zeroed out, then you'd only see the first line of the image repeated over and over in the output file.

Comment: I litteraly looked at the memory dump and didn't noticed. I thought rowPitch is the offset into a row and commented the line out. Thanks guys!

Comment: I remain unconvinced there is a barrier requirement.

Comment: @Jherico read [Memory Domains](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-dependencies-available-and-visible), then [Fence Signal](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-fences-signaling) access scopes, then for comparison how it looks if op **does** include memory domain [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-submission-host-writes). Then report to Khronos Group any inclarity you may have. Also consider why would `HOST` otherwise exist (as said above).